# Termination of my spatially coupled (convolutional) LDPC code

Tags: matrices, information-theory, coding-theory, parity

I am following two references to build up my SC-LDPC encoder. I may refer to them as [1] and  [[2]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4568447) from now onwards.

I used [1] to build up my parity check matrix, which is of dimension 
$(M(L \cdot d_v + d_v - 1), \quad M \cdot d_c \cdot L) $. I used the following parameters:

- $M = 4$
- $L = 1352$ (I want to encode an information block of $k = 5400$ length.
- $d_c = 4, d_v = 3$

After successfully building it up using section 3 in ref. 1, I needed to terminate my code to ensure that the encoder was returning to zero state. This is, according to reference 2 I would need to append 8 bits to the information message to efficiently terminate my code. The problem is, that I would be supposed to get a syndrome termination of $p_L = 6$ length according to equation 16 from [2](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4568447). On the contrary I do get a sequence of 8 bits, which are supposed to be derived from the number of checks in my parity-check matrix, but I don't know how to make this match with my expected length for $p_L$.

[1]: '*An efficient method to construct parity-check matrices for recursively encoding spatially coupled LDPC codes*' (easibly traceable through Google search)